# Two definition of the same item in the same div class

Tags: html, css

I need to use an item, in this case img, in the same div class but with different definitions.

Example:

```
section .row img {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid #18a00e;
}

section .row img {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    border: 4px solid #18a00e;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

How can I create and use this two definitions without the last one overwriting the former?
Thank you.

Later edit (for more info):

```
//this is the html code scenario 1 where I need the width: 100%//
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
           <img src="img/m3.jpg"/>
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>

//this is the html code for scenario 2, where I need max-height: 300px//
<section class="jumbotron">
    <div class="unlockedl">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="img/pm1.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It depends on your markup. Can you post your markup, too?

Comment: You need to add extra/different selectors to refer to one or the other. These don't need to be classes. But it is not possible to recommend a suitable solution without seeing the HTML of both elements.

Comment: I am new to coding, using bootstrap. I do not know what a markup is.

Comment: @Claudiu your markup is your HTML structure.

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You have classes that you can use to uniquely target those elements. use `.container` and `.jumbotron` to target the `.row img` in those individual sections instead of the generic `section` element.

```css
.container .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #18a00e;
}

.jumbotron .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  border: 4px solid #18a00e;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="img/m3.jpg" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="unlockedl">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="img/pm1.jpg" />

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can also use other unique classes/elements in those 2 blocks, like `figure` and `.unlockedl`

```css
section figure img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #18a00e;
}

section .unlockedl img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  border: 4px solid #18a00e;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="img/m3.jpg" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="unlockedl">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="img/pm1.jpg" />

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Or you can use `:nth-child()` to target individual sections

```css
section:nth-child(1) .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #18a00e;
}

section:nth-child(2) .row img {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  border: 4px solid #18a00e;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <img src="img/m3.jpg" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="unlockedl">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="img/pm1.jpg" />

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an unique id and assign the css to the distinct id

```
 <div id ='id1'  class='same_class'>    </div>
 <div id='id2'  class='same_class'>     </div>


#id1 {
  width: 100%;
}

#id2 {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.same_class{
   margin: 0 0 30px;
   border: 4px solid #18a00e;
 }
```

Comment: Styling with ID's can be troublesome because of CSS specificity. If you're going to modify the markup to add a distinct ID, why not just add a distinct class and use that to style instead?

Comment: @MichaelCoker   correct .. but the id is the most selective of the select and could help the OP ..

Comment: Anyway answer update grouping the common elemnt i same_class